# Vue & Sockets: Handling sending messages back and forth

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, socket.io

I have a simple implementation, or an attempt at one, of a messaging system just to show an alert of a message to different users. I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io Vue Socket Io but it's just a socket.io.  I am attempting to have the client subscribe to an event in mounted.  The name is based on their userID. The problem is that my implementation below doesn't work to show the alerts.  I can see the event being subscribed to in mount and I can see sending message console log in the server so I know that is getting fired but I don't see the `alert` being triggered by the `emit(`Chat_`....`

server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('sendMessage', function (data) {
       console.log("Sending message to" + data.user);
       socket.emit(`CHAT_${data.user}`, data.msg)
    });
 });
```

client:

On the client, the `userIDSelf` is a user ID that is passed in as a prop.  It's the User's logged in ID and in `mounted`, they automatically subscribe to the a chat channel with their userid appended to it, like a custom channel.

```
mounted() {
    this.sockets.subscribe(`CHAT_${this.userIDSelf}`, (data) => {
         alert(data)
    });
},
```

there is a function `sendMessage` that takes the values from 2 inputs (not seen) in the template.  You have to enter a user ID on who you want the message sent to and then another input with the actual message.   These are sent over to the backend server listed above.

```
methods: {
  sendMessage() {
        this.$socket.emit('sendMessage', {user:  this.userIDReceiver, msg: this.message})
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a logical problem here. In your server code

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('sendMessage', function (data) {
    console.log("Sending message to" + data.user);
    socket.emit(`CHAT_${data.user}`, data.msg)
  });
});
```

the `socket` (User 123) which emitted `sendMessage` event to the server, will eventually also be the `socket` which will receive the emitted `CHAT_456` event from the server. But User 123 `socket` only listens to `CHAT_123` events. The socket is sending itself a message but doesn't receive it.

---

### Possible Solutions

#### **A - the `room` approach**

Once a socket connects on the server, throw it in a `room` based on it's user id. This requires sending the userid to the server during connection, e.g. with a query parameter. In the client just add a `token` query parameter to the connection string like

```js
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io("https://server-domain.com/?token=" + userid);
```

and through the connecting socket in a room (join) on the server side like

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  const userid = socket.handshake.query.token;
  socket.join(userid);
});
```

then your socket `sendMessage` would work like this

```js
/* ... server side */
socket.on('sendMessage', function (data) {
  console.log("Sending message to" + data.user);
  io.to(data.user).emit('chatMessage', data.msg);
});
```

#### **B - the `keep reference to the socket` approach**

Internally every socket has a `socket id`. Normally these are not exposed the user/clients. However you do have a unique `user id`. So let's keep a `user id / socket instance` - relation on the server side, so you can get a reference to the socket object for each corresponding user, using the user id.

The most basic example for it would be a in-memory store on the server side

```js
let socketRefs = {};
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  const userid = socket.handshake.query.token;
  socketRefs[userid] = socket;
});
```

then your socket sendMessage would work like this

```js
/* ... server side */
socket.on('sendMessage', function (data) {
  console.log("Sending message to" + data.user);
  let targetSocket = socketRefs[data.user];
  targetSocket.emit('chatMessage', data.msg);
});
```

Comment: thanks Pascal!  `But User 123 socket only listens to CHAT_123 events. The socket is sending itself a message but doesn't receive it.`. -- can't a socket, regardless of what socket it is, emit an event and whoever is subscribed to it, get it?   The userId is being passed in and the socket is emitting to `CHAT_${USERID}` and _whoever_ is subscribed to that, would get that.....right?

Comment: This would require in using `io.emit` instead of `socket.emit` on the server. If you use socket.emit it only emits to this socket. If you use io then it gets emitted to all sockets in the default namespace.

Comment: ahh that makes sense, thanks so much for responding to this and the detailed options above in your answer!

Comment: There are many other options you will discover quickly when experimenting around. Glad i could help !

Comment: one more thing if you don't mind.  If I do what you mentioned and change it from `socket.emit` to `io.emit('CHAT_${data.userID}', data.msg)` , is that an "ok" way to handle it?  I noticed you didn't mention it was one of the 2 options in your answer so that's why I'm wondering if it's not a great approach :).Thanks again!

Comment: I guess there are a few other options I haven't thought about. But using `io.emit` in particular I guess "could" be problematic since it's emitting the message to all sockets, regardless if the message is meant for the socket or not - could be a bad idea security wise either not to mention. There are legit use-cases for `io.emit` but your particular use-case I thought is not one of them.

Comment: I wouldn't put to much thought about it for starters, if it works it works. But if you building something AAA "production"-like I would at least consider all options there are.